# PHP assigning a condition statement to a variable?

Tags: php

I have a variable holding the structure of a table, I want to add php code inside the table. I've tried adding the code statement to a variable and then fetching the variable data inside the table but I Think is not possible, what is the right way of doing it.

```
$table='<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>
        <td width="638" valign="top">**ADD CODE HERE**</td></tr>
        </table>';
echo $table;
```

Here is the code i want to add inside the column:

```
if($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-err'])
    {
        echo '<div class="err">'.$_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-err'].'</div>';
        unset($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-err']);
    }       
if($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-success'])
    {
        echo '<div class="success">'.$_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-success'].'</div>';
        unset($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-success']);
    }
```

I've tried adding the code inside $notification and then adding

```
$notification='if($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-err'])
    {
    echo '<div class="err">'.$_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-err'].'</div>';
        unset($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-err']);
    }       
    if($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-success'])
        {
        echo '<div class="success">'.$_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-success'].'</div>';
        unset($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-success']);
        }';
```

> ' . $notification . '

Inside the table like:

```
$table='<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>
            <td width="638" valign="top">' . $notification . '</td></tr>
            </table>';
echo $table;
```

But is not possible, is there a way to achieve this? i am a newbie

Comment: why is it not possible? any errors? looks like you are missing a semi colon

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Comment: Don't do multiline assignments/echoes. Use [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc)s instead. You're also missing a `;` at the end of the `$table = ...` line.

Comment: I added the semicolumn, also i tried enclosing the statement in single and double quotes but i get more errors Parse error: syntax error, unexpected `T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT added your unsets...

```
if($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-err'])
    $notification = '<div class="err">'.$_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-err'].'</div>';
if($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-success'])
    $notification = '<div class="success">'.$_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-success'].'</div>';

unset($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-err']);
unset($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-success']);

$table='<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>
        <td width="638" valign="top">' . $notification . '</td></tr>
        </table>';
echo $table;
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you just chuck the content you want into the $notification variable?

```
   var $notification=""; // is 'var' idiomatic PHP? Not used it much lately.
   if($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-err'])
     {
       $notification= '<div class="err">'.$_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-err'].'</div>';  
       unset($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-err']);     
     }
  if($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-success'])
     {
        $notification = $notification . '<div class="success">'.$_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-success'].'</div>';
         unset($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-success']);
   } 

  $table='<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>             <td width="638" valign="top">' . $notification . '</td></tr>             </table>';     
  echo $table;
```

However, there are a couple of things that seem odd to me about this.

Firstly, why have a separate Session variable for an error or success message? Why not have `$_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-outcome']` ? Then you don't need to switch like that.

Also do you need to `echo` the table at all? Why not just have your `$notification` variable available to the page and then have the table doing its thing like this in the page:

```
<table><tr><td>$notification</td></tr></table>
```

Finally, you had better not be using that table for anything other than the display of tabular data or you will make kittens cry. It looks suspiciously as though you might be planning to use it for page formatting.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    // snipped code
    $table='<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>
           <td width="638" valign="top">' . $notification . '</td></tr>
           </table>'
    echo $table;
    // snipped code
?>
```

This can be rewritten like this:

```
<?php
    // snipped code
?>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="638" valign="top"><?=$notification?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
    // snipped code
?>
```

Much cleaner, no?

The `if` statements also have alternative syntax which I find much easier to follow.

```
<?php
// snipped code
if($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-err'])
{
echo '<div class="err">'.$_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-err'].'</div>';
    unset($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-err']);
}       
if($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-success'])
    {
    echo '<div class="success">'.$_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-success'].'</div>';
    unset($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-success']);
    }
// snipped code
?>
```

This can be rewritten:

```
<?php
// snipped code
?>

<?php if($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-err']): ?>
    <div class="err"><?=$_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-err']?></div>
    <?php unset($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-err']); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-success']): ?>
    <div class="success"><?=$_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-success']?></div>
    <?php unset($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-success']); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
// snipped code
?>
```

Now, if any errors occur, it will be much easier to debug and follow.

Comment: Is there some sort of online syntax formatter for php? to make code more readable?

Comment: There's PHPLint: http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/

It is a code validator. I'm not sure it formats code. Any text editor can do that. I think TextMate, Sublime, Eclipse, etc, can all do formatting.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is perfectly correct just that you are not assigning values properly to the notification variable. This should work now.

```
 if($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-err'])
 {
   $notification= '<div class="err">'.$_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-err'].'</div>';  
   unset($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-err']);     
 }
if($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-success'])
 {
    $notification = $notification . '<div class="success">'.$_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-success'].'</div>';
     unset($_SESSION['Mmsg']['Mreg-success']);
 } 

$table='<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td width="638" valign="top">' . $notification . '</td></tr></table>';     
echo $table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. I'm trying to guess whats your problem, try this:

```
$table='<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>
        <td width="638" valign="top">' . htmlentities($notification) . '</td></tr>
        </table>';
echo $table;
```

see if this works